# Looking for e-commerce SaaS for remote add to cart and custom product option

Tags: e-commerce, custom-attributes, saas

we are looking for an e-commerce SaaS that will allow for this specific functionality:

- It needs to allow a product to be added to cart from a remote URL
- This product will require a unique value to be attached to it each time before it is added to cart

So for instance from a remote website the user could enter their pet's name and this value would be assigned as an option value to the product.

Ideally this software would allow us to integrate with PHP, but not a deal-breaker.

I'm sure we have done something like this before with Magento but was hoping for a lighter-weight option such as shopify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end we decided to simply use FoxyCart as that gave a lot of control over the basket.

Answer (score 0):

[Ecwid](http://ecwid.com) is a SaaS shopping cart, it can be embedded into the page on your site (i.e. it is not on a remote page) and embedding can be in a visual form (store or other widgets) or merely as JavaScript library, and it allows you to put products to cart with a JavaScript call on the page.